# queer behavoir of std::map

Tags: c++, stdmap

I have a

```
std::map<a,std::vector<b>> m;
```

a is a struct

```
struct a
{
  std::string c,d;
bool operator<(const a &o)
{ return !(c==o.c && d==o.d);}
}
```

I am populating the map this way

```
for(/*blah blah*/)
{
  m[A].push_back(B)
}
```

and after populating i am printing some stuff

```
std::cout << "Size:" << m.size() << std::endl;
int i=0;
for(std::map<a,std::vector<b>>::iterator it = m.begin(); it != m.end();i++,it++)
{
   std::cout << "[" <<i <<"] " << it->second.size() << std::endl;
}
```

and the output i am getting is

```
Size: 12
[0] 1
[1] 3
```

can someone explain why map::size() is showing 12 while it iterates over just 2 elements?

Comment: Sorry what are you asking, that your loop only iterates twice when the map size is 12 or why the vector size goes from 1 to 3?

Comment: updated with more information

Comment: `d==0.d` - that's a zero where an `o` should be. Are you really showing us your actual code?

Comment: No its not actual code, and how does the a::operator< affect here

Comment: A map is an ordered container. It builds a binary tree. Therefore it needs to know whether a particular element goes before or after another element. `operator<` is used for that by default. Yours completely breaks `map`'s contract (expectation). In your implementation, `a < b == b < a`. A useable `operator<` should be enough to sort the keys.

Comment: I find this question quite interesting. Although, sadly, there is no [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) here, I made myself a compilable version using some of the code above (VS2012, I had to adapt some things). Depending on the keys the programm crashes even in some cases. Matt provides the solution below. @Matt: Great answer!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change the comparison function to

```
bool operator<(const a &o) const
{
    if ( c == o.c )
         return d < o.d;

    return c < o.c; 
}
```

Note that making it a non-member function is more useful in general.

Your comparison function has to follow these rules:

> If we define `equiv(a, b)` as `!comp(a, b) && !comp(b, a)`, then the requirements are that comp
>   and equiv both be transitive relations:
>
> — `comp(a, b) && comp(b, c)` implies `comp(a, c)`
>
> — `equiv(a, b) && equiv(b, c)` implies `equiv(a, c)`

The map uses the comparison function in generating its data structure and iterating over it, so if your function is wrong then anything can happen.

Comment: That is not a sorting function. Sorting is sorting, comparison is comparison.  `a < b` does not sort anything, it tells whether `a` is smaller than `b`.

Comment: doesn't it become more complex to compare if number of elements to compare becomes larger??

Comment: @tejashs Yes, it does. That is one of the reasons [`std::tie`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple/tie) is so cool.

Comment: @tejashs: Yes, just use Matt's solution.

Answer (score 2):

Out of curiosity, I tried this code in VS2010. It won't compile.

```
bool operator<(const a &o) { return !(c==o.c && d==o.d); }
```

Error as follows.

> error C2678: binary '<' : no operator found which takes a left-hand operand of type 'const StdMapTest::Exec::a' (or there is no acceptable conversion)

```
bool operator<(const a &o) const { return !(c==o.c && d==o.d); }
```

The above line compiles, but throws an assertion:

> Expression: invalid operator<

Finally I tried this.

```
    bool operator<(const a &o) const { return (c == o.c) ? d < o.d : c < o.c; }
```

Compiles and seems to work correctly.

I think it would be fair to say that a good enough compiler would have made this question unnecessary. I'm sure VS2010 is not the only one that can perform this kind of diagnosis.

Comment: your first error suggests that your code was using the map via a const reference (which OP's code didn't)